# How do I resolve conflicts in an exported conda environment from macOS when installing on linux?

Tags: python, conda

I have an [`environment.yaml`](https://gist.github.com/cjw296/528fb24361b28792e012bd3b1b668bfc#file-environment-lock-yaml), that I use to re-create conda environments as follows:

```
conda env create -p /home/chris/moneybox/env --file /home/chris/moneybox/environment.lock.yaml --force
```

On macOS, this works fine, on linux it fails after 30+ minutes with conflicts, but the output is, to me at least, impenetrable and I'm not able to figure out what I need to change.

I've put the output up as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/cjw296/528fb24361b28792e012bd3b1b668bfc#file-conda-conflicts-output-txt). I can't make any sense of it, and while I've submitted a [conda issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10136) to try and get that improved, would anyone be able to tell me what's actually conflicting here and what changes I need to make to `environment.lock.yaml` to fix them?

Comment: Yeah, the conflicts reporting is 99% useless. Does the env need all those packages and specific versions? E.g., I would never have a `ca-certificates` or `openssl` version pegged in a YAML since such high-vulnerability packages are frequently deprecated and sometimes purged. If you already have a version of the env created, perhaps try exporting a more minimal specification via `conda env export --from-history`.

Comment: The intention of the .lock.yaml is to have a fully reproducible environment, so yeah, *everything* should be pinned. Where is the "deprecation and purging" process documented? And how *do* I get usefulness out of the other 1%?

Comment: Purging is not openly documented AFAIK, but one can see it happens (e.g., [`anaconda::ca-certificates` only has files for last 2.5 years](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/ca-certificates/files)). While Conda aspires for cross-platform support, the solves often lead to platform-specific packages, and so ultimately a full YAML (all packages and versions) is not inherently cross-platform. If you want everything running absolutely identical software across platforms, then containers are likely a better solution ([additional discussion here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9257)).

Answer (score 2):

Package requirements on macOS and linux are not always the same.  And even when the requirements match perfectly, the set of available versions is not always identical.  (Maybe `conda-forge` contains `foobar-1.2.3` for linux, but `foobar-1.2.4` for macOS.)

For those reasons, it is usually not possible to export a large environment's package list from macOS and expect it to work on linux, or vice-versa (in my experience, at least).  Once an environment gets large enough, the probability becomes high that at least one package's requirements cannot be satisfied.

Therefore, you'll need to maintain two different `environment.lock.yaml` files, for macOS and for linux.  Since you're starting with a file that works on macOS, one easy thing to try is to simply drop the patch versions from all of the requirements and see if conda can work with that.

So, I tried that on your file.  It worked fairly quickly.  (I will add the new lock file as a [comment on your gist](https://gist.github.com/cjw296/528fb24361b28792e012bd3b1b668bfc#gistcomment-3409636).) Admittedly, this is not ideal -- nearly half of the packages ended up with a slightly different version.  You'll need to test the environment to make sure it still suits your needs.

If you really want the two environments to match as closely as possible, you could try iterating over the differences and reverting them one at a time until you encounter a failure.  But that seems like more trouble than it's worth.  Maybe a better strategy is to just look over the differences and see if any of them stand out to you.  You know your use-case; maybe there are one or two packages you need to be really picky about, so hand-pick those versions and leave the rest alone.

Comment: _You know your use-case; maybe there are one or two packages you need to be really picky about, so hand-pick those versions and leave the rest alone._ This is likely the easiest situation. They could even focus only on the top-level dependencies, and let Conda figure out the rest.